# Meteor reactivity best practices when working with long running processes

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

Here is the scenario for which I am trying to come up with a good solution.

1. A user click a button in the browser.
2. The process spinner is displayed.
3. That executes a method on a server.
   3.1. Method adds a message to a queue.
   3.2. Method stores the `message id` and `status` in a Mongo collection.
   3.3. Method returns the same message id to browser.
4. At some point in future, the the `status` for the same `message id` gets updated in the Mongo database.
   4.1 The process spinner is no longer displayed

What would be the best way to take care of step 4.1? I would really like to avoid the old-fashioned-way approach of executing AJAX requests every few seconds to determine the state of the message.

Comment: Can you afford (in terms of efficency) publishing a part of your messages collection to the client? That way they'll receive updates as soon as the status of the message changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about your exact problem to give a precise answer, so here are my assumptions:

1. There is a collection called `Queue` which contains all of the requests being processed.
2. All of the entries in `Queue` which pertain to the current user are published.
3. A spinner should be shown while any of the user's items are being processed (only slight revision is required if this isn't true).

Here's an example [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) which will toggle a spinner element as needed:

```js
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (Queue.find({status: 'processing'}).count()) {
      $('#spinner').show();
    } else {
      $('#spinner').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could toggle the spinner directly in the template like so:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#unless isQueueEmpty}}
    <div class="spinner"></div>
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  isQueueEmpty: function() {
    return Queue.find({status: 'processing'}).count() === 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: I like the second idea. Running jQuery actions like show and hide is a bit anti-pattern in Meteor.

Comment: Agreed. I included it only because `#spinner` may not be in the same template as the `autorun` (maybe it's in a nav bar or something).

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'displaySpinner' template with your spinner component, and conditionally show it using a template.helper 'processing' that returns true if item status is 'processing':

```
{{#if processing}}
  {{> displaySpinner}}
{{/if}}
```